# RandomFunction with a QueueingProcess for more than one service handler hangs, why?

Tags: bugs, random-process

In Mathematica, I want to, say, investigate a M/M/4 queue, that is a single queue with 4  services each handling jobs from that same queue.  The arrival rate is 4 and the service rate is 2.  I've imposed no limits on the size of the queue, i.e. the queue can hold an infinite number of items.  WL seems to accept the following definition comfortably:

```
svcCount = 4;
sp = QueueingProcess[4, 2, svcCount];
QueueProperties[sp, "QueueDiagram"]
QueueProperties[sp]
```

[image]

WL comes back with sensible values. I can even plot a diagram depicting the probabilities of the different queue sizes using:

```
\[ScriptCapitalS] = StationaryDistribution[sp]
DiscretePlot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalS], x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But when I try to simulate the working of that queueing system with `RandomFunction` as explained in the documentation ([In `QueuingProcess` see the first of the "basic examples"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QueueingProcess.html)), Mathematica hangs or the computation is not terminating for some unfathomable reason:

```
data = RandomFunction[sp, {0, 15, 1}]
```

Use "Abort Evaluation" to abort the computation and gain access to the notebook again.

If I set `svcCount = 1`, i.e. I configure the queueing system to have a single queue, everything works fine.

My question: is this (most  likely) a bug or is my application too naive and in that case, how do I run a simulation of a queueing system with multiple service handlers, i.e. `svcCount > 1`?

Thanks.

Comment: I just checked. The code you have provided works fine on 12.1.

Comment: Which version and operating system are you using? Works in 12.1.1 on Win 8.1

Comment: @Edmund, I'm running  Mma 12.0.0 on MacOS 10.14.6  (Mojave) 16 GB RAM, 3.5 GHz Intel Core i7

Comment: @PlatoManiac, I'll try it on my work laptop, there I run 12.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received a response from Wolfram Support confirming that it concerns a bug which is solved in version 12.1.